# Concatenate All Rows From One Column With MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to do something that I thought would be very simple but it's driving me crazy.

I have the following data:

```
ID     ---    Name
1      ---    Joe
2      ---    Bob 
3      ---    Jim
4      ---    Mike
```

I want to be able to show the results of this from MYSQL as:

`"Joe", "Bob", "Jim", "Mike"`

I tried CONCATENATE tutorials, but they all seem to be for merging like ID's.

```
$sql = "SELECT names, CONCAT_WS('', 'names') as namelist FROM peoplenames";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

echo $row["namelist"];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $names = $row["nameslist"];
        echo $names;
    }
}
```

If I echo outside the loop I only get the most recent result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the contents of `$names` each time round the loop.

Change your code like this

```
$sql = "SELECT names FROM peoplenames";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$names = NULL;

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $names .= sprintf('"%s",',$row['names']);
    }
    // output amalgamated date
    rtrim($names, ',');
    echo $names;
}
```

Comment: Yes.. .yet another spellchecker at your service ;-)

Comment: Ahhh, my spell checker is in the house

Comment: It's almost a *live-in* version too. I don't do windows though.

Comment: ^ same here. Glad to be back after 2 weeks vacation... but kinda wish I was still over there lol - hahaha I knew you'd come up with a *nix joke ;-)

Comment: This is working to concatenate all the names. However the separator isn't working. So I am seeing JoeBobJimMike instead of "Joe", "Bob", "Jim", "Mike"

Comment: meaning... that I said "I don't do/wash windows" you know what I mean ;-) I was going to edit it after and saying "but I do do Linux"... just not "that" way hehe

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nova Scotia, by the sea.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You more than likely may have flown right over me lol you need to visit the Maritimes :-) including PEI and Cape Breton.

Comment: Is the $names = null; necessary? I removed it and this code still worked.

Comment: Its not strictly necessary, but it is always good practice to initialise variables

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'd call that green ticky, an assist ;-) good show.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I would have to agree. Now its been closed as a duplicate, se la vie

Comment: @RiggsFolly et oui, c'est la vie mon cher ami.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thought so, you spelt it correctly. Never been colder than the week in winter I spend in Montreal. But I loved the year I spent in Toronto.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Montreal's nice, but the traffic/drivers are murder. I think I felt safer driving in Toronto lol

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to SELECT names FROM peoplenames and use PHP concat for a string:

```
$names = "";

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $names .= '"' . $row["names"] . '",';
}

echo $names;
```

Comment: I am trying to take this result and put it into an array. When I use PHP to add the separator I only get one name to show. IE it shows "Joe", and not "Joe", "Bob", "Jim", "Mike"

Comment: Did you try the solution I provided?  Note that the loop concats the names and then the names are echoed OUTSIDE of the loop.

Comment: Sorry Rob, your solution looks like it should work. This was my fault, it looked like something I had been working on earlier, but your code is more solid. Only problem I have now is getting the quotes to show correctly. IE it shows Joe, Bob instead of "Joe", "Bob"

Comment: Updated my answer.  You need to manually concat the string with the quotes.